# JSF + PrimeFaces = FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando JSF + Primefaces, no código de uma tela
tem o seguinte botão

```
<b:commandButton value="Pesquisar" look="primary"
                            style="width:100%" process="@form" update="@form"
                            actionListener="#{relatorioFrequenciaService.listarBancas()}">
                        </b:commandButton>
```

Quando clico no botão ocorre a seguinte exceção

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [facesServlet] in context with path [/spe] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Either HTTP 500 or java.lang.Throwable error page is required in web.xml or web-fragment.xml. Neither was found.
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handleAjaxException(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:353)
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handle(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:322)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at br.com.infosolo.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Alguém já teve esse problema e sabe como resolver? Abraços